# Filtering by Wordpress category id not working

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy

I'm trying to filter my home page loop to 1 post in the category id of 34. I have multiple custom post types with the custom taxonomy ID 34 assigned to them. I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
 <?php query_posts('showposts=1&cat=34'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `tag`

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=1&cat=34'); ?>
```

Comment: I updated it and still  "Sorry, but the requested resource was not found on this site."

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'customposttypename','category' => 'catslugname', 'posts_per_page' => 1 )); ?>
```